# How/Where to declare the version of Java to use in React Native project?

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, configuration

I'm new to the world of Java and Android. Been working a bit with React Native and really like it so far. I have noticed that React Native works best with Java 8.

From what I understand, one can have as many versions of Java installed as needed. You just have to declare in your project settings which version to use.

My question: Where/how do I specify Java 8 for React Native if I have multiple versions of Java installed, i.e. Java8 & Java10?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Dave